# CSS font-size and padding styling not working properly on Ipad

Tags: html, css, netlify

I have coded a responsive website and deployed it on Netlify. I checked it on my Windows laptop and Android and iPhone, it is working as it should. When I check it on my laptop, it appears to perfectly work on tablets too, including iPad. But for some reason on iPad, CSS is not working properly. On my original code, I had used variables, then I tried not to use variables. I also tried using

```
  appearance: auto;
  -moz-appearance: auto;
  -webkit-appearance: auto;
```

and

```
appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

But still the same problem persists.
Here are my code dedicated for tablet size:

```
:root {
  font-size: 62.5%;
      
  --h1-size: calc(2rem + 3vw);
  --h2-size: clamp(2rem, calc(1.2rem + 2vw), 4rem);
  --h3-size: clamp(2rem, calc(1.2rem + 2vw), 3rem);
  --h4-size: clamp(1.65rem, calc(1rem + 1.5vw), 2rem);
  --p-size: clamp(1.5rem, calc(0.8rem + 1.5vw), 2rem);
}

   /***************************** min-width: 750px *****************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  #welcome {
    background-position-x: 150%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    background-size: 70%;

    padding-bottom: 8rem;
    padding-bottom: calc(2.5 * var(--h1-size));
  }
  .welcome-text {
    place-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 2;

    padding: 1.6rem 0px 5px 3rem;
    margin-top: 2.4rem;

    padding: var(--p-size) 0px 5px var(--h1-size);
    margin-top: calc(0.8 * var(--h1-size));
    grid-column: 1/6;
  }

  .welcome-text h1 {
    font-family: var(--curlyFont);
    font-size: 6rem;
    font-size: clamp(4rem, 10vw, 10rem);
  }

  .welcome-text a {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .projects a * {
    max-width: 70%;
    margin: 7px auto;
  }

  .about-us-text {
    padding-bottom: 1.65rem;
    padding-bottom: var(--p-size);
  }

  hr {
    width: 7%;
  }

  #skills {
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-top: var(--h1-size);
  }

  #skills ul li {
    grid-column: span 6;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    text-align: center;

    margin: 2.4rem;
    margin: var(--h2-size);
  }

  #skills ul li img {
    max-width: 30%;
    width: 90px;
    justify-self: center;
    margin: var(--p-size) auto;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  #skills ul li#design {
    grid-column: 1/13;

    justify-self: center;
  }

  #skills p.leading {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: calc(var(--p-size) / 1.1);
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    line-height: var(--h4-size);
  }

  #contact {
    background-size: 34%;
    padding-top: 7rem;
    padding-bottom: 6rem;
    padding-top: calc(2 * var(--h1-size));
    padding-bottom: calc(1.8 * var(--h1-size));
  }
}

/***************************** min-width: 930px *****************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 930px) {
  .site-nav h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-size: var(--h3-size);
    padding-left: 4rem;
    padding-left: var(--h1-size);
  }

  #welcome {
    background-position-x: 120%;
    background-position-y: 30%;
    background-size: 60%;

    padding-bottom: calc(2 * var(--h1-size));
  }

  .welcome-text {
    place-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0 0px 5px calc(1.8 * var(--h1-size));
    grid-column: 1/6;
  }

  #about-us {
    padding-top: calc(var(--h1-size) * 1.5);
  }

  .about-us-img {
    padding-top: calc(var(--h1-size) * 1.2);
    padding-left: 0;
    grid-column: 2/7;
    grid-row: 1;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: top;
  }
  .about-us-img img {
    max-width: 25vw;
    padding-top: calc(0.8 * var(--h1-size));
  }

  .about-us-text {
    /* grid-column: 7/12;
    grid-row: 1;
    align-self: center; */
    padding-top: calc(1.5 * var(--h1-size));

    grid-column: 6/11;
    grid-row: 1;
    align-self: center;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: calc(1.2 * var(--h1-size));
    /* padding-top: calc(2.1 * var(--h1-size)); */
  }

  #contact {
    background-size: 30%;
  }
  #skills h3 {
    padding-bottom: calc(var(--h1-size) * 1.5);
  }
  #skills .leading {
    padding-top: calc(var(--h1-size) * 1.5);
  }

  #skills ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

  #skills ul #copywriter {
    grid-column: 1/5;
    grid-row: 1;
    align-self: center;
    padding-top: 150px;
  }
  #skills ul #delivery {
    grid-column: 5/9;
    grid-row: 1;
    align-self: start;
  }

  #skills ul li#design {
    grid-column: 9/13;
    grid-row: 1;
    padding-top: 150px;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
  }

  #skills ul li img {
    max-width: 40%;
    width: 120px;
  }

  #contact ul.social-media-icons li.gmail,
  #contact ul.social-media-icons li.fb {
    grid-column: 4/8;
  }
}
```

The issues are, padding and font-size. For some reason, the padding and font-size is stuck at reset level. font-size is 10px, and padding is zero.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the common queries i used for optimizing for ipad

**For general iPad layouts**

```
 @media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
```

**For portrait layouts only**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
```

}

**For landscape layouts only**

```
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
```

Comment: I tried it out, but it didn't help at all.